# carrierwave not saving image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, carrierwave

i'm using Angularjs as front end,
i'm able to upload image along with some parameters .
i'm using this directive angular-file-upload to upload single image with parameters:

```
uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader(
  url: '/recipes',
  alias:  'cover',
  removeAfterUpload:  true,
  #transformRequest: angular.identity,
  headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrf_token,'accept': 'application/json'},
  withCredentials: true
)


uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = (item)->
          #data = angular.toJSON($scope.recipe)
          item.formData.push("recipe": angular.toJson($scope.recipe))
          #item.upload()
          console.info('uploader', $scope.uploader);
          uploader.uploadAll()
```

**this is the create action:**

```
def create
    params[:recipe] = JSON.parse params[:recipe]
    params[:recipe][:cover] = params[:cover]
    @ingredients = Ingredient.where(:id => params[:recipe][:ingredients].map {|ingredient| ingredient[:id]})

    @recipe = current_user.recipes.new(params.require(:recipe).permit(:name,:instructions))
    @recipe.ingredients << @ingredients
    @recipe.user_id = current_user.id
    @recipe.save
    render 'show', status: 201
  end
```

**recipe model :**

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base

  mount_uploader :cover, AvatarUploader
  belongs_to :user

  has_and_belongs_to_many :ingredients,:join_table => "ingredients_recipes"

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
  attr_accessor :cover
end
```

this is the request :

```
-----------------------------100101598926016265538511946
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="recipe"

{"name":"amzpld","instructions":"mpzmdpzmez","ingredients":[{"id":3,"title":"oeuf"}]}
-----------------------------100101598926016265538511946
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cover"; filename="10.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

ÿØÿà�JFIF������ÿÛ�� ( %"1"%),...383,7(-.+



0& $,,,2,,,,,,4,4,,,,,,,,,-,,,,,,,,,,,4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,ÿÀ��¨,"�ÿÄ�������������
�ÿÄ�@�����!1AQa"q2¡±#BRÁáð3bÑr$ñCT¢ÿÄ��������������
ÿÄ�0�������!1A"Qaq¡2±#B3CÑáðÿÚ���?�öá]®Qâ1  Bs(À¡V_D$¯8þ&¡i6¨Û)Ò
´oóçÊ�dÌôªçñEÏêÚÙ]ëãzn£hÓÚêÄ6I½&&·¼ßËðËÌ§)L¤hGQÞ°Pf�MÔúSkÔBønàôÕjal3YðäKÇÖ¾Á¢@..........
```

the recipe is saved but with cover = nil 
plz what i'm missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making `:cover` part of your `params[:recipe]` hash:

```
params[:recipe][:cover] = params[:cover]
```

But you're not white-listing it, so instead of:

```
 @recipe = current_user.recipes.new(params.require(:recipe).permit(:name,:instructions))
```

Try this:

```
 @recipe = current_user.recipes.new(params.require(:recipe).permit(:name, :instructions, :cover))
```

### update

You also have another issue in your `Recipe` model, you're using:

```
attr_accessor :cover
```

Remove that line, you don't need it because `cover` should be a real column in your `recipes` table, and if that column already exists this will override the method that assigns values to that column, thus causing your column to contain `nil`.

Now if you don't have that column in your `recipes` table, just add it using a migration, in your console type:

```
rails g migration add_cover_to_recipes cover:string
```

and then migrate:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Hope that solves your issue.

Comment: `cover` is still `nil` ?

Comment: yes it is :  `[{"id":120,"name":"ùmspam","instructions":"losap","cover":null,"created_at":"2015-12-08T22:34:00.124Z"
,"ingredients":[{"id":2,"title":"oeuf","created_at":"2015-11-24T16:20:16.454Z","updated_at":"2015-11-24T16
:20:16.454Z"}],"user_id":1}]`

Comment: Please put `byebug` at the beginning of your `create` action, and when you get the debugging console check `:cover` contents: `puts params[:cover]`

Comment: `puts params[:cover]
#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb3711afc>
nil`

Comment: @SalemHarrathi Hey, I just noticed that you're using "attr_accessor :cover" on your model. Why are you doing this? `cover` should be a real column in your `recipes` table.